# Как подключиться к TCP-серверу используя прокси?

Tags: c#, proxy, tcp

Здравствуйте, нужно подключиться к TCP-серверу используя прокси C#

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18291295/1291717

Answer (score 0):

Используйте класс System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx